# Protect website by using function from another domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a client, who wants a website on wordpress. I agreed to do that, but he demand to do it on his own ftp. I would like to protect myself in case he doesn't want to pay and change ftp password.

I thought that the good idea is to call the php function from another domain (my domain), so if he doesn't pay i will change the code from my domain and his website will crash.

Is it good, secure idea to protect myself?

Comment: I'd say no. But I'm not an expert in this. Just to be clear you want to create a backdoor on your clients webpage that you can use to crash it? What if someone accidentally finds this backdoor, how are you going to explain that to your client in case he/she pays as agreed?

Comment: Yes i want to create backdoor, i have a copy on my computer and it would be nice solution to make possibility to delete this backdoor is he pay

Answer (score 0):

No that's not a good idea,

If the code on his server makes a call to check whether it should work or not, it's not that hard to get that check removed. If you don't trust your client make a contract with him and sign it both. Also you could start by developing the website on your own domain and then when he's satisfied and payed move it over to his.

But as long as he has the code, there's little you can do to prevent that code from working on your command.